# Why doesn't onbeforeunload send requests in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a request that saved data to the database when it is sent. It is necessary that when the user refreshes the page, the data is also saved. I use such an event as `onbeforeunload`. Safari does not wait for the server request to be executed when the page is reloaded, which is why it is not possible to save the latest changes, in other browsers such a problem does not occur.. Who has faced a similar problem and can help me with something? (and it is possible to find or advice another solution to the problem) I would be grateful. I use Vue js.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // The code after restarting the browser.
});
```

Comment: Maybe you'll have more luck with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

Comment: Safari's behavior is correct; you can't stop the user from navigating away, or people'd lock you on a site with a long-running AJAX call. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out a similar story

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
   navigator.sendBeacon("/save", data);
});
```